# Exceptions handling patterns for .NET library - handle, leave unattended or rethrow?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, design-patterns, class-library

I'm writing a C# library, whose `DLL` will be later used by code of other application(s).

When there is a statement in the library that could throw an exception such as `System.IO.IOException`, should I catch it then and there itself or should I leave it to be caught by the program of the application that uses it?

I ask this because, I have not caught the exception in my library. When debugging my application (that uses the library), Visual Studio shows it to me as an **unhandled exception** in the library. But when I <kbd>> Continue</kbd>, the program continues and the exception is caught by the application. It seems to be working fine.

Now, is it okay to do this - i.e., could there be any problems when the application is deployed? Or should it be absolutely caught in the library itself? Or does MSDN suggest somewhere, something better than this as a "best practice"?

Comment: If you can do something to recover from the exception then you should catch it and do your recovery logic. Otherwise just let it bubble up and make sure you document what exceptions your library may throw.

Comment: The api of your library should make some exceptions "impossible" by validating the input and throwing library exceptions if the passed input is invalid. These exceptions should be very clear about how to solve them. IOExceptions that are thrown should bubble up, but you could wrap them in another library exception with some explenation on to how it couldve happened this exception rised. Explicitness is key

Comment: Do not compromise your library design just because you have a debugging option set wrong.  Use Debug > Windows > Exception Settings and click the checkbox for "Common Language Runtime exception" to reset it.

Comment: Your library should handle your proprietary code's exceptions not framework/system.io like exceptions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a good library is an art and science. Assuming that you have already decided on functionality provided and exposed relevant APIs to consumers of the library it seems that one problem remained unresolved - exception handling.

In general exceptions which will be raised during library code execution could be divided into two groups:
1. Dependent on library implementation and functionality.
2. Dependent on consumer or system and out of area of interest for your library.

IMHO best practice would be to define all exceptions which are thrown by library code and derive them either from `ApplicationException` or better yet from relevant .NET exception with your lib specific prefix i.e.: `<LibShortName>FormatException` or `<LibShortName>InvalidOperationException`. Then if your library should throw exception to client code use library derived exceptions.

If there are exceptions raised outside of library and they are meaningful from your lib functionality perspective you can catch them and either throw new library exception containing as an internal exception already catched exception or use your `<LibShortName>AggregateException` to create chaining of exceptions before exposing them to clients.

The above scheme is used in many popular .NET libraries i.e. SharpSkia. There are other approaches to the problem, however, I find the above one most informative for library consumers - they get as much information on error as possible. Furthermore they can easily use type based patterns in catching and handling exceptions.

One of the most important aspects of writing good libraries is performance. To get best one for you library never use exception for control flow in you code. Exceptions should be used exclusively for error conditions. One of good examples of bad design violating the above pattern was `ANTLR C# parser framewrok` AFAIR v2. At some stage library was using exceptions for controlling parsing logic what was extremely inefficient. Later it was refactored to use exceptions only for error conditions improving performance by several orders of magnitude.

Finally one of the best books on designing .NET library APIs is:

- [Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries](https://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Development-ebook/) by Krzysztof Cwalina and Brad Adams.

What could be an interesting read these are discussions on `API Reviews` in closed and open issuess from [.NET Core corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20label%3Aapi-approved%20) repository and a bit old but still a classic one Krzysztof Cwalina blog posts tagged with [General API Design](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/tag/general-api-design/)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: MS recommends explicitly against deriving library exceptions from ApplicationException: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/using-standard-exception-types